Unable to execute bash script with cronjob rhel 9
I have created a user called abcservice with useradd abcservice --shell /usr/sbin/nologin and I have a bash script(auto.sh) with the contents:
#!/bin/bash

# Download Python script from S3 bucket
aws s3 cp s3://myscript/local_account.py /tmp/local_account.py

# Run the script
# The script will push the report to S3 bucket
sudo python3 /tmp/local_account.py

My cronjob settings are * * * * * /bin/bash /tmp/auto.sh (for testing)
For some reason, abcserviec is unable to execute the cronjob... The auto.sh has permission of 777
I've check the user, group, /var/log/messages, IAM roles and policies, SELinux, and crond. The auto.sh can be executed normally manually.

While the script indeed does not look right to me (aws is most likely not in the PATH, since you never set a PATH for the script), I don't see a reason why it should not execute. You don't even need x-permissions on the script; permission 0444 would be sufficient. You don't describe what steps you took to prove, that the script indeed has not been executed.

Try this with your cronjob: * * * * * /bin/bash /tmp/auto.sh >> output.log 2>&1
I think the issue might be the AWS command in auto.sh is not set up correctly. You may need to use the full path for the AWS command in your auto.sh script. You can find the full path by running this command: which aws.
/path/to/command/aws cp s3...
